# Meteor update timestamp

Tags: meteor

I've successfully implemented a "created" time stamp using the [UMFAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database) (pronounced *um-fack*), but I can't get the "updated" timestamp working (which the UMFAQ alludes to but does not provide a code sample for).

Here's my code:

```
Posts.deny({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        doc.created = new Date(); // timestamp
        return false;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
        doc.updated = new Date(); // timestamp
        return false;
    }
})
```

When I insert an object into the collection via the Chrome console, I get a "created" timestamp. However, when I update that record (using $set) I don't get an "updated" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to alter the `modifier` for an update :

```
Posts.deny({
    ....
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
        if(modifier.$set) {
            modifier.$set.updated = new Date();
        } 
        return false;
    }
});
```

The check to see if `$set` is there is to prevent an error in case the client were to send an update up without using `$set`.